# How do you make a batch file that merges files together?

Tags: batch-file

I have to merge files in a folder to a single text file and I'm not sure how to do that

Answer (score 3):

Use FOR /F: http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html

For example, to concatenate all the text files in the current directory and any subdirectories, you could do:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %G IN ('dir /b /s *.txt') DO TYPE %G >> out.txt
```

Comment: `type` works with wildcards. In case there's no sub dirs simply `type *.txt > out.txt` can be used.

Comment: BUT its add file name as first line for each file. Just run this in cmd.exe inside folder and all subdirs txt files go to out.txt.

Answer (score 2):

copy /b *.txt newfile.txt

make sure all the text files are in the same folder along with the .bat

Comment: And to specify all the files individually, you use a `+`.  E.g., `copy /b file1.txt +file2.txt +file3.txt newfile.txt`.

Comment: @tuxy117 I'm trying to merge log files into a single text file. Can you elaborate what you are saying to do a little more?

Comment: So I suppose that all of the files that you want to merge are .log files. What you would want to do is have all of those files in the same folder and either command line into the folder or drop a bat file into the folder. The command that you need is "copy *.log newfile.txt" this copies all the .log files into a text file named newfile

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple redirection operator with command `type`

suppose your directory contains 3 files `a.txt b.dat` and `myfile`

then just use `type * >> outfile`
this will copy contents of all the files to file named `outfile`