# Windows script to merge all .html files in a directory and its subdirectories into a single .html file?

Tags: merge, text-files, windows-scripting

I have a `Results` directory, which has many subdirectories each containing a HTML file with a specific naming format, `_ExeReport.html`.

I want to write a Windows script which merges each of those files into one file.

For now, I tried running two commands :

```
dir /S *_ExeReport.html
```

This is listing all the files (with some extra information), and:

```
copy /b *.html final.html
```

This is merging all the files in current directory into one file.

But, I am not able to write a script which can combine and do everything I need.

Can someone help me with this? I am newbie to scripting languages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you make a batch file that merges files together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314867/how-do-you-make-a-batch-file-that-merges-files-together)

Comment: @T3RR0R : yes it helped. Thanks : my final command : FOR /F "tokens=*" %G IN ('dir /b /s *_ExeReport.html') DO TYPE "%G" >> MergedOutput.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @T3RR0R for sharing the link. My final command :

FOR /F "tokens=*" %G IN ('dir /b /s *_ExeReport.html') DO TYPE "%G" >> MergedOutput.html